# Aurelia + Webpack with a shared legacy jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, aurelia

I have an aurelia app which is being bundled by webpack.  We have a separate legacy js file which has some click bindings on buttons that I would like to be able to drop into place.  For now we can say the separate file looks like below:

```
    (function (window, $) {

      $(function () {
        console.log($('.btn'); //this always shows length 0!!
        $('.btn').on('click', function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          console.log("button was clicked");
        });
      });

    })(window, jQuery);
```

I can get the file imported in via webpack, however the jquery click listeners don't seem to work.  Is there an easy way to get this brought in on a global level so that all the buttons used in the app can listen on these click events? Also when I console.log $('.btn') it always has a length of 0 even though there are .btn classes on the page.

Answer (score 0):

What is probably going on is that your function is being called before the elements have been attached to the page. So, you're adding listeners to objects that don't exist yet.

I can see 2 ways to solve your problem without changing much code:

1 Call your function in the `attached()` hook of every custom-element. *not a nice thing to do*

2 Use event delegation, changing your script to:

```
(function(window, $) {
  $('body').on('click', '.btn', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("button was clicked");
  });
})(window, jQuery);
```

Hope this helps!